# Macro for preventing of entering duplicates in column M in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I need to write a macro sub for preventing of entering duplicates in column M in excel.

Ex:

I enter "A - 100" in cell M5
If I enter "A - 100" in cell M7 I want to show me an error message that is duplicate.

I tried Data validation but the formula does not work, so I want to use a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Intr As Range, M As Range, r As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, t As String

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set M = Range("M:M")
    Set Intr = Intersect(M, Target)
    If Intr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In Intr
        t = r.Text
        If t <> "" Then
            If wf.CountIf(M, t) <> 1 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    r.Select
                    r.ClearContents
                    MsgBox t & " has already been entered."
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as ***.xlsm*** rather than ***.xlsx***

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: basically its working but if I enter a duplicate its opening the VBA code page.  I need something more user oriented.
Thanks